# How to remove break on converting XML to String type in Flex?

Tags: xml, string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I want to convert one XML type value to String type value and for that I am using **toString()** method to achieve that but problem is that on converting from XML to String I am getting some "\n"(Break statement) in that string variable.

But I don't know why that is coming, I am currently using the following codes for conversion:

My XML is:

```
var text:XML = new XML(<HTML>
<BODY>
<P ALIGN="left">
  <FONT>
    <FONT SIZE="32">
      Some Text Here
    </FONT>
  </FONT>
</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>);
```

Following code I am using for converting XML to String:

```
var textString:String = (text.normalize()).toString();
```

But if  I am checking the variable **textSring** then I am getting the following result:

```
<HTML>\n  <BODY>\n    <P ALIGN="left">\n      <FONT>\n        <FONT SIZE="32">Some Text Here</FONT>\n      </FONT>\n    </P>\n  </BODY>\n</HTML>
```

But I don't know why "\n" is coming after converting to String.

If anybody can find where I am doing wrong so that I am getting the result like this and how to resolve this problem please help me to solve.

Comment: \n is a linebreak. have you tried text.toXMLString()? And wait woah if you're doing one type you'd just treat it like an object and pass it in a String() right? (with xml properties you'd use @)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solves the problem

```
var textString:String = (text.normalize()).toString().split("\n").join("");
```

Answer (score 2):

- `\n` means **new line**. This happens when `enter` key is pressed (eg: while making your XML text).
- Did you **directly** copy/paste the XML text from another program? I would not expect Flash IDE to think your `enter` presses must become `\n` in text. An external program might pass such "new line" instructions along with the copied text as part of display instructions.

Option #1 : Try without `normalize` function (is it better?).

```
var textString:String = text.toString();
```

Option #2 : Try to keep same multi-line formatting.

```
var textString:String = (text.normalize()).toString();
textString = textString.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Option #3 : Just clean the string by removing all the `\n` chars (loses multi-line fomatting).

```
var textString:String = (text.normalize()).toString(); 
textString = textString.replace("\n", "");
trace ("textString is : " + "\n" + textString);
```